# Group data by one column and creating a new column based on a rows in each group

Tags: sql

I have 'Task' and 'Start time' columns in my data. For each Task, there may be one or more Start times. What I want to do is, categorize each task as an 'X' task if all its Start times are equal and as a 'Y' task if all its Start times are not equal.

This is how the table should look like :

[image: https://imgur.com/a/RQPzPu9]

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a group by and counting the distinct start time and using a case to return X or Y.

```
Select task, 
    (case when count(distinct start_time) = 1 then 'X' else 'y' end) 
  from tasks 
  group by task;
```

or this if you want it to look exactly like the picture.

```
  Select tasks.task, tasks.start_time, new.new
  from tasks, (Select task, 
      (case when count(distinct start_time) = 1 then 'X' else 'y' end) as new
    from tasks 
    group by task) as new
  where tasks.task = new.task;
```

You can view my solution [here](https://paiza.io/projects/Zu7IBFc-5tFBK8xDuf3hPg?language=mysql) https://paiza.io/projects/Zu7IBFc-5tFBK8xDuf3hPg?language=mysql P.S. I just use Integer instead of date because I didn't feel like dealing with dates lol.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select task, 
    (case when count(distinct start_time) = 1 then 'X' else 'y' end) 
  from tasks 
  group by task;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `group by task` get the value of `new_column` for each task and then join to the table `tasks`:

```
select t.id, t.task, g.new_column 
from tasks t inner join (
  select 
    task, 
    (case when count(distinct starttime) = 1 then 'X' else 'Y' end) new_column 
  from tasks 
  group by task
) g on g.task = t.task
```